# Figuring out dimensions for a DW

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, warehouse

I have the following database schema from which I want to create DW with the needed dimensions for the following KPIs:

- Number of personel by training (formations)
- HR turnover
- Absences by category

[image: Employee database]

What I'm trying to figure out is which dimensions should provide the contextual information for the facts table.

Comment: the schema provided contains french words while the question is in english. Can you describe what are the tables (in english) and relations found in the database

Comment: Personnel (Employee), Formation(Training), Conge (Vacation - Days off), and each category is for a department.

Comment: How HR turnover are detected from the data?

Comment: When one employee changes from one department(category) to another, that's considered as a turnover. (Internal hr turnover)

Comment: @Baha you've got the right answer, why not accepting it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following suggestions are based on your comments:

1. To extract **Absences by category** you need to specify CATEGORIE and ABSENCE tables as dimensions.
2. To extract **Number of personnel by training (formations)** you need to specify FORMATION table as dimension
3. To extract the **HR turnovers** you need to specify CATEGORIE table as dimension

Comment: If I was to add a location table, should it be considered as a dimension?

Comment: Yes it should, if it didn't store facts